# Buffer Overflow exploitation to get a shell

Tags: linux, security, 64-bit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I've spent hours trying to figure out the problem about my exploitation.
I tried to exploit the vuln-machine explained in this page: https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/binary-exploitation/64-bit-stack-based-buffer-overflow .
My program keeps going in segmentation fault.
ASLR is already disabled and the C program is compiled with:
`gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack vulnerable.c -o vulnerable` .
My payload is made as following:
`python3 -c "print ('A'*104 + '\x0e\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00')"` where `0x7fffffffe30e` is the addrress of the env variable setted following the guide on the same page (address obtained through the getenvvar C program).
Can someone help me? Thank you.

I used the following command to try to get the shell: `(python3 -c "print ('A'*104 + '\x0e\xe3\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00')"; cat) | ./vulnerable`

Answer (score 0):

On my x86_64 GNU/Linux system at least, the *address obtained through the getenvvar C program* is wrong. It works to *adjust for program name* if that is accounted for once instead of two times, i. e. changed:

```
    ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]))*2; /* adjust for program name */
```

to

```
    ptr += strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2]);   /* adjust for program name */
```

Note that it's important that the second argument to *getenvvar* is exactly (as long as) the path used when running the *vulnerable* program.

Comment: The address of the environment variable is right. I did everything as it is written in the ired.team page, unless i used python3 commands. not python. What is the problem then :/. In the end, after running the following command: (python3 -c "print('A'*104+'\xea\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00')"; cat) |
./vulnerable, where 0x7fffffffe2ea is the address of the PWN var, I get Segmentation fault

Comment: How do you prove that: _The address of the environment variable is right_?

Comment: I added the following to the vulnerable code: char *ptr = getenv("PWN"); printf("%p", ptr);

Comment: Did you determine the `104` as described under [Finding RIP Offset](https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-injection-process-injection/binary-exploitation/64-bit-stack-based-buffer-overflow#finding-rip-offset), or did you just take it from the example?

Comment: Yes, of course I did it that way. I used pattern create and pattern offset in gdb/gef